# uniform convergence- sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

How can I prove that $f_n(x)=2/\sqrt n$ is uniformly convergent to cero in the interval $x \in (0, \infty)$? It obviously the sequence goes to cero but I would like to bound the limit with another function in order to use the definition of uniform convergence.

For any $\epsilon >0, \exists  n_0\in N:$ any $n> n_o, |f_n-f|<\epsilon$

Thank you very much!!

Comment: All caps is considered shouting. Also, you must have mistyped, there seems to be a variable missing.

Comment: sorry for the capital letters. Yes, I forgot to say $x\in (0,\infty)$

Comment: What is $x\in(0,\infty )$ in relation to the problem. Do you mean $f_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $f=0$.

Comment: @Any, is something eating $x$s here?

Comment: @Blanca, what is $f_n(x)$? You still do not say.

Comment: If there really is no $x$ in the right hand side of $f_n(x)=\dots$, i.e. if each $f_n$ is a constant function then you only have to show that the sequence $\left(\frac2{\sqrt n}\right)_n$ converges to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $n$ such that $|\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}|<\epsilon$. Rearrange to obtain an expression (inequality) for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is it possible to take $n_0=4/\epsilon^2$?

Comment: Is it possible to take n0=4/ϵ2? –  Blanca 13 hours ago 
  
As long as you take the integer part of it. Can take $n_0$ to be the largest integer smaller than $\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}$(we need $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$). Sub this back into inequality and check.